# Create a library with codenameone to use on iOs and android

Tags: codenameone

I was wondering if it is possible to create a library with codenameone that can be used in a native iOs/Android/... App. This library should contain the business-logic and the rest of the app should be implemented native.

Is thought this isn't possible, but the technical advisor of a client insists that this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread the original question, you are correct its impossible to do this and impractical to do this since the size of the library will be too big. If you want to create a library for iOS with Java the best approach would probably be J2Obj-C which was designed specifically for that purpose: https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/

Originally I had referenced these which allow you to create library projects for use with Codename One which might be the source of the confusion:

http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/07/jaring-and-libraries.html

http://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html

Comment: How can I access such a library from a native iOs/xCode project? Could you please point me to some sample code? I'm a bit lost it seems ...